# How to clear margins between responsive divs in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, margins

I have this code in a bootstrap project and I can't put responsive divs side by side with no margins between them. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```css
.container-vip {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #09C;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="container-vip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="container-vip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="container-vip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="container-vip">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: where you don't want margin? can you explain?

Comment: create new css rule to override the bootstrap style that sets the margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not margins, it is padding, and you can remove it using `padding: 0px` on your `col-*` divs.

Answer (score 1):

You just need add a class to your div like

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 no-padding">
    <div class="container-vip">
    </div>
  </div>
```

and add css for it in your own .css file

```
.no-padding{padding: 0 !important;}
```

and of course you can give your own name instead of "no-padding"

Comment: That´s it. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to the bottom of your custom css file

```
.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3{
background:red;
padding:0px;
}
```